# Longer distance inbetween table rows not line breaks

Tags: tables, line-breaking

Id like to make the distance between the rows bigger, if I do that the linebreaks also increase in size, which is unwanted since the objective is to isolate the lines to clarify which symbol and texts are tied.
I am using it inside a wrap table enviroment to let text be on the left side

```
\newpage\subsection{Current Loop}\label{CurrentLoop}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{3.9cm}\vspace{-0.52cm}
\footnotesize
\onehalfspacing
\caption{Annotation and their explanations for the current loop}\label{AnnotationsCurrent}
\begin{tabular}{p{4mm} p{2.8cm}}
    \textbf{I}                      & is current, even throughout the section\\
    \textbf{$\vv{J}$}               & is the current density vector\\
    \textbf{$\vv{dl}$}              & is the line segment vector\\
    \textbf{$\mu_{0}$}              & is the vacuum permeability\\
    \textbf{$\vv{B_n}$}             & is the B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
    \textbf{$\vv{B_{\perp n}}$}     & is the perpendicular B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
    \textbf{$\vv{B_{\parallel n}}$} & is the parallel B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
    \textbf{$\vv{R}$}               & Radius from center to a segment\\
    \textbf{d}                      & distance from center to probing point \textbf{$P_b$}\\
    \textbf{$\psi$}                 & is the angle between \textbf{d} \& $\vv{r}$\\
    \textbf{$\vv{r}$}               & is the vector from segment \textbf{n} to $P_B$\\
    \textbf{$\hat{\mathrm{r}}$}     & is the unit vector\\
    \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{wraptable}
To theoretically analyze the behavior of a coil, a great model to analyze is a closed loop, where we consider it to be one turn of a coil. The model is imaginary and would not be realistic to use outside of the theory.\\
We consider a loop where the current is constant, and we divide this loop into 24 evenly-sized sections of wire for simplicity of the calculation. At last, we believe infinite sections are a more accurate version of a coil. The ring is made out of a conducting material.
To find the B-field of section 1, the below formula is used
\begin{equation}\label{BfieldSection1}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}}{\mathrm{r}^2}
\end{equation}
The single-loop coil model is illustrated in figure xx.
The B-Field of the sections can be split into a parallel component and a perpendicular component. When this is done, we see the diametrically opposing sections, which allows us to see that they cancel each other out.
\begin{equation}\label{totalBfield24SegmentVersion}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\text {tot }}=\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}+\cdots+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}
\end{equation}Knowing all of the sections are parallel and have the same direction, we can take the length and add them up
\begin{equation}
\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\text {tot }}\right|=\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}\right|+\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}\right|+\cdots+\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}\right|
\end{equation}
The first section of the looped current segment is calculated 
\begin{equation}\label{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment}
\left|\vv{B}_{\| 1}\right|=\left|\vv{B}_1\right| \sin \psi=\left|\vv{B}_1\right| \frac{R}{\left(d^2+R^2\right)^{1 / 2}}
\end{equation}
$\vv{dl}$ and $R$ are perpendicular this lets us write \eqref{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment} into
\begin{equation}
\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1\right|=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{d}^2+\mathrm{R}^2}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}`

Comment: `\textbf{$\vv{J}$}` could more easily be written `$\vv{J}$` as `\textbf` has no effect on math

Comment: Thank you for all the advice. Sorry, I was unaware of the minimal working example, I will remember that for any posts later on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,esvect,wrapfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\setlength{\intextsep}{3pt}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Current Loop}\label{CurrentLoop}

\begin{wraptable}{r}{3.9cm}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\footnotesize
\caption{Annotation and their explanations for the current loop}\label{AnnotationsCurrent}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  $I$                    & is current, even throughout the section\\
  $\vv{J}$               & is the current density vector\\
  $\vv{dl}$              & is the line segment vector\\
  $\mu_{0}$              & is the vacuum permeability\\
  $\vv{B_n}$             & is the $B$-field at segment $n$\\
  $\vv{B_{\perp n}}$     & is the perpendicular $B$-field at segment $n$\\
  $\vv{B_{\parallel n}}$ & is the parallel $B$-field at segment $n$\\
  $\vv{R}$               & Radius from center to a segment\\
  $d$                    & distance from center to probing point $P_b$\\
  $\psi$                 & is the angle between $d$ and $\vv{r}$\\
  $\vv{r}$               & is the vector from segment $n$ to $P_B$\\
  $\hat{\mathrm{r}}$     & is the unit vector\\
\end{tabularx}
\bigskip
\end{wraptable}

To theoretically analyze the behavior of a coil, a great model to analyze 
is a closed loop, where we consider it to be one turn of a coil. The model 
is imaginary and would not be realistic to use outside of the theory.

We consider a loop where the current is constant, and we divide this loop 
into 24 evenly-sized sections of wire for simplicity of the calculation. 
At last, we believe infinite sections are a more accurate version of a coil. 
The ring is made out of a conducting material.

To find the $B$-field of section 1, the below formula is used
\begin{equation}\label{BfieldSection1}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1=
\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}}{\mathrm{r}^2}
\end{equation}
The single-loop coil model is illustrated in figure~xx.
The $B$-Field of the sections can be split into a parallel component and 
a perpendicular component. When this is done, we see the diametrically 
opposing sections, which allows us to see that they cancel each other out.
\begin{equation}\label{totalBfield24SegmentVersion}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\mathrm{tot}}=
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}+\cdots+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}
\end{equation}
Knowing all of the sections are parallel and have the same direction, 
we can take the length and add them up
\begin{equation}
|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\mathrm{tot}}|=
|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}|+|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}|+\cdots+|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}|
\end{equation}
The first section of the looped current segment is calculated 
\begin{equation}\label{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment}
|\vv{B}_{\| 1}|=|\vv{B}_1| \sin \psi=
|\vv{B}_1| \frac{R}{(d^2+R^2)^{1 / 2}}
\end{equation}
$\vv{dl}$ and $R$ are perpendicular this lets us write \eqref{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment} into
\begin{equation}
|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1|=
\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=
\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=
\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{d}^2+\mathrm{R}^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

If you add `\onehalfspacing` for the document, be sure to do `\singlelinespacing` for the `wraptable`.

You should also fix the various inconsistencies in notation: sometimes you have `$r$` and other times `\mathrm{r}` similarly for `dl`; also you have `\vv{B_{\parallel n}}` in the table, but `\vv{B}_{\| 1}` in the text: either the arrow always cover the subscript or never (and `\|` is not the same as `\parallel`, although often they print the same). Note that `\textbf` does nothing in the first column of the table (other than producing other inconsistencies).

I removed all `\left` and `\right` commands, because you can see that they produce oversized delimiters. You may want `\bigl|` and `\bigr|` (not needed, in my opinion), but with `\left` and `\right` the bars are really too long.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help all of your advice has been helpful! If you know why The Table 1 text is not in line with the text next to it I would also love to know, as of now I've manually adjusted the table upwards with \vspace{-"value"}

Comment: @user299605 I'd not try that, so not to fool the reader.

Answer (score 1):

- you should provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example), that we see which packages and definitions related to your problem you have loaded in your document preamble
- for increasing vertical space between table rows is (usually) used `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` , as mentioned @DavidCarlisle in his comment or use packages which enables to define this (as are  `cellspace` or `tabularray`
- a possible solution with use of the `tabularray` package is:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esvect}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}
\subsection{Current Loop}\label{CurrentLoop}
    \begin{wraptable}{r}{3.9cm}
\vspace{-1.7\baselineskip}
\caption{Annotation and their explanations for the current loop}\label{AnnotationsCurrent}
\footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[l, mode=math] 
                              Q[l, wd=28mm, font=\linespread{1}\selectfont] @{}}
                 }                        
\textbf{I}              & is current, even throughout the section\\
\vv{J}                  & is the current density vector\\
\vv{dl}                 & is the line segment vector\\
\mu_{0}                 & is the vacuum permeability\\
\vv{B}_n                & is the B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
\vv{B}_{\perp n}        & is the perpendicular B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
\vv{B}_{\parallel n}    & is the parallel B-field at segment \textbf{n}\\
\vv{R}                  & Radius from center to a segment\\
\mathbf{d}              & distance from center to probing point $P_b$\\
\psi                    & is the angle between \textbf{d} \& $\vv{r}$\\
\vv{r}                  & is the vector from segment \textbf{n} to $P_B$\\
\hat{\mathrm{r}}        & is the unit vector
\end{tblr}
    \end{wraptable}
To theoretically analyze the behavior of a coil, a great model to analyze is a closed loop, where we consider it to be one turn of a coil. The model is imaginary and would not be realistic to use outside of the theory.\\
We consider a loop where the current is constant, and we divide this loop into 24 evenly-sized sections of wire for simplicity of the calculation. At last, we believe infinite sections are a more accurate version of a coil. The ring is made out of a conducting material.
To find the B-field of section 1, the below formula is used
\begin{equation}\label{BfieldSection1}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}}{\mathrm{r}^2}
\end{equation}
The single-loop coil model is illustrated in figure xx.
The B-Field of the sections can be split into a parallel component and a perpendicular component. When this is done, we see the diametrically opposing sections, which allows us to see that they cancel each other out.
\begin{equation}\label{totalBfield24SegmentVersion}
\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\text {tot }}=\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}+\cdots+\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}
\end{equation}Knowing all of the sections are parallel and have the same direction, we can take the length and add them up
\begin{equation}
\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\text {tot }}\right|=\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 1}\right|+\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 2}\right|+\cdots+\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_{\| 24}\right|
\end{equation}
The first section of the looped current segment is calculated
\begin{equation}\label{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment}
\left|\vv{B}_{\| 1}\right|=\left|\vv{B}_1\right| \sin \psi=\left|\vv{B}_1\right| \frac{R}{\left(d^2+R^2\right)^{1 / 2}}
\end{equation}
$\vv{dl}$ and $R$ are perpendicular this lets us write \eqref{FirstLoopedCurrentSegment} into
\begin{equation}
\left|\vv{\mathrm{B}}_1\right|=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}} \times \hat{\mathrm{r}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{r}^2}=\frac{\mu_0 \mathrm{I}}{4 \pi} \frac{|\vv{\mathrm{dl}}|}{\mathrm{d}^2+\mathrm{R}^2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this (close to) what you looking for?

Comment: Thank you for helping I am very much still a rookie and have used mathpix for majority of the math I see the inconsistencies you are speaking of thanks for mentioning those as well! The red bar on the right side should not be empty, the goal is to have the text wrap around the table where the annotations are explained!

Comment: @user299605, red lines just show page layout. As noted in MWE code, this part of preamble should be remove in the real document.